# mod_dav_svn replacement in java?

Tags: java, svn

Is there a replacement for mod_dav_svn in java that I could deploy to tomcat/jboss?  I have a fully java envrionment that I'd like to integrate subversion into without deploying apache.  I've found libraries for subversion in java but not an actual dav based service.

Thanks
Marc

Comment: Do you need HTTP/WebDAV access, or can you use the `svnserve` server (with or without `ssh`)?

Answer (score 1):

It just got possible now thanks to [SVNKit](http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/trunk/svnkit-dav):

For an example take a look here:
[SCM-Manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager)
or here:
[Raysforge](http://raysforge.net/viewProject.xhtml?fn=Raysforge)